# Validating private properties data annotations in class

Tags: c#

I have a class that has a private property that has a custom Required attribute. The validation will not work if the property is not public. Is there a way to validate private properties?

POCO

```
    public class MyPOCO
    {
       [Required(nameof(SomeId))]
       private int? SomeId { get; init; }

       public int Id => SomeId!.Value;
    }
```

Validation method is called

```
    public static class ValidatePOCO
    {
       public static bool IsValid(object myPoco)
       {
          var validationResults = new List<ValidationResults>();
          ValidationContext ctx = new(myPoco);
          // assume SomeId is null - [Required] works if the property is public and not private
          bool isValid = Validator.TryValidate(myPoco, ctx, validationResults, true);

          return true;
      }
    }
```

I call the IsValid method with the POCO. The value of SomeId is null at this point.

New here so if my question requires formatting, I can provide more context to the question but I tried my best. Thank you.

Tried looking for online resources and couldn't find anything

EDIT
The way my POCO is binded is using ConfigurationBinder

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("path to json").Build();

var poco = new MyPOCO();
config.Bind(poco, co => co.BindNonPublicProperties = true);

bool isValid = ValidatePOCO.IsValid(poco);
```

My JSON: intentionally commented out to get null

```
{
   // "SomeId": 123
}
```

Comment: Your requirement is a bit odd.  If the property is private, how can an external user possibly set it?  The "Required" attribute doesn't really make sense.

Comment: It is bounded using IConfigurationBinder (which is outside the context of this - not sure if that part is really important for my question but I can add it in). It can allow private fields to be binded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround - `TryValidateValue` on each property value.

`ValidateProperty` fails with nullable types by throwing exception - not sure how feed nullable properties into validator. Thankfully, `ValidateValue` worked - but we have to pull all property attributes and cast them to `ValidationAttribute` - fix the code if you have attributes that can't be casted to `ValidationAttribute`.

Side note: not sure where `Validator.TryValidate` comes from, I see only `Validator.TryValidateObject`, but this should not be an issue.

My solution is written using .NET 7

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Reflection;

var myPoco = new MyPOCO();

Console.WriteLine("POCO is valid: " + ValidatePOCO.IsValid(myPoco));

public class MyPOCO
{
   [Required]
   private int? SomeId { get; init; }

   public int Id => SomeId!.Value;
}
public static class ValidatePOCO
{
    public static bool IsValid<T>(T myPoco)
    {
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        foreach (var property in properties.Where(x => x.CanWrite))
        {
            var ctx = new ValidationContext(property);
            var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes().Cast<ValidationAttribute>();
            var isValid = Validator.TryValidateValue(property.GetValue(myPoco, null), ctx, validationResults, attributes);

            Console.WriteLine($"Property {property.Name} is valid? {isValid}");
            if (!isValid)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look into TypeConverters, you can change the way properties are binded via the 'init'. Before I attempt to bind, I override the default converters (so for example, boolean uses BooleanConverter). I make a custom one and then reset it after my bind is done.

Link to boolean converter (I have a few for int, bool and enum types)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.booleanconverter?view=net-7.0

Comment: i am not sure I followed that. you imply that you have way more complex implementation in MyPoco class that uses TypeConverters? could you update code in the question to reflect this?

Comment: I just tried this and while this address an issue I didn't think of, the issue I am having on binding the one private variable from the json. I realized the method 'Bind' has an override that access an Action<BinderOptions>? that I can set BindNotPublicMembers to true. By default, it is false. It works now.

Comment: Just to add, yes, I have validation attributes on some of my properties that are not of type ValidationAttribute but just slightly modified your answer and just used LINQ before the cast. `property.GetCustomAttributes().Where(attr => attr is ValidationAttribute).Cast<ValidationAttribute>();`